# Как правильно организовать цикл без использования if-else в Unity3D ?

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
if ( currentXPosition < endXPosition ) {
    transform.Translate( new Vector3 ( velocity * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0 )); // задает направление движения обьекта с заданной скоростью
} else if ( currentXPosition == endXPosition ) {
        transform.Translate( new Vector3 ( - ( velocity * Time.deltaTime ), 0, 0 )); // обратное направление
} else if ( currentXPosition == startXPosition ) {
    transform.Translate( new Vector3 ( velocity * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0 ));
            } // думаю тут понятно...
```

Итак, я хотел  сделать скрипт для движения платформы "туда-сюда", скрипт выше. 
Как организовать это дело через цикл, стоит ли ? Как можно упростить скрипт ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Мне кажется, что упростить предложенный код можно примерно следующим образом`:`

> - Учтите, кстати, что в приведенном вами `snippet'e` некорректно производится сравнение вещественных чисел — рекомендую [**соответствующий референс**](http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm) по теме.
> - Еще в этом фрагменте кода есть логическая ошибка — после прохождения пути слева направо ваша платформа останется у правого края и будет там *"барахтаться".*

```
    private void EnsurePositionIsValid()
    {
        if (currentXPosition < startPosition ||
            currentXPosition > endPosition)
        {
            // Можно также восстановиться от некорректного положения
            // объекта, например, передвинув его к ближайшей границе.
            throw new Whatever(...);
        }
    }

    private bool ShouldGoForward()
    {
        return currentXPosition == startXPosition ||
               currentXPosition < endXPosition;
    }

    EnsurePositionIsValid();
    float x = Time.deltaTime * (ShouldGoForward() ? velocity : -velocity);
    transform.Translate(new Vector3(x, 0, 0));
```

Comment: @Sier

- Попробуйте "прогнать" ваш код в голове — в случае, если `currentXPosition == endPosition` (отбросим проблемы точности), вы считаете, насколько должна измениться координата за `deltaTime` и отодвигаете объект влево на это значение.

- Сразу же после этого (когда производится обновление положений объектов на следующий фрейм) вы попадаете в условие `currentXPosition < endPosition` и двигаете объект, но уже **вправо.** Дальше история повторяется и, естественно, что влево он никогда не поедет.

Comment: @Sier

- Правильный подход здесь следующий — храните для объекта вектор его скорости (или даже только одну проекцию на ось абсцисс, поскольку остальные у вас не юзаются) и в момент, когда объект подходит к границе (слева или справа) меняйте этот вектор на противоположный.

- Этот подход можно заменить на пару `{float velocity, bool goingForward},` но лично я не вижу в этом смысла.

Comment: и ведь все было перед глазами...спасибо за помощь ;)

Comment: Отчаянные вы ребята. Зачем вообще тут сравнивать floatы через ==, start position и end position, вызывать какие-то странные методы алокирующие еще больше векторов каждый проход. Все значительно проще. 

x(t) = A*sin(omega*t+alfa) + beta. A - амплитуда, omega - частота, alfa - начальная фаза, beta - смещение относительно начала координат. Можно даже прямо в шейдер или матрицу эту формулу вставить и все. Основная проблема будет только в том чтобы откалибровать её нормально, чтобы за экран не выезжала.

Comment: @igumnov

- Вы действительно предлагаете автору заменить подход с равномерным перемещением объекта на перемещение по синусоиде только по той причине, что вам это кажется *проще*?

- Задумываться о количестве аллокаций векторов в языке с `GC` — абсурдно.

Comment: - Попробуйте написать `snippet`, в котором движение по синусоиде **можно приостановить,** а затем продолжить и сравните сложность логики с подходом, где для объекта хранится вектор его скорости, который меняется на противоположный при приближении к границам.

- Как вы будете "перекалибровывать" ваш подход в том случае, если область движения изменится? Писать метод-ининициализатор, рассчитывающий `α, A, ω, β`? Серьезно?

Comment: Ну если ему зачем то нужно прямо совсем-совсем равномерное движение можно использовать вместо синуса треугольный сигнал. Это 100% проще чем проверять каждую итерацию платформу на столкновение с конечной точкой
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_wave

Если нужно чтобы платформа еще немного стояла в конечной точке, то трапецоидный сигнал уже спешит на помощь.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041498/equation-for-trapezoidal-wave-equation

По поводу GC согласен, но все равно проще сразу писать весь выход сразу в матрицу, а не вектор и сразу паковать её в шейдер.

Comment: Чтобы останавливать ее в произвольной точки траектории без условных переходов нужно простой инкремент времени которое подается в уравнение заменить на какую-то другую функцию которая учитывает остановки. То есть уравнение сигнала заменяется на:

    x(t) = > x(stop(t))

Правда в в самом теле stop(t) могут быть условные переходы но тут я не вижу тривиальных решений разве что использовать хэш таблицу.

Comment: По поводу перекалибровки то и при первом и при втором подходе все равно надо менять одинаковое количество параметров. По сути второй подход просто обобщение первого.

V - omega;
Start Position, End Position - A, beta;

alfa можно оставить 0 она не сильно влияет на поведение платформы.

P.S. Лучше вообще ее не делать много раз. Один раз вставить ее туда проинициализировать через параметры конструктора и вообще забыть.